# not able to connect to WIFI which has no PSK

Tags: networking

if I want to connect to a WIFI its not prompting for the password and remains on encrypted?

any hint?

its not even possible if I set the SSID and PSK for a new network
So I am only able to connect to the network which I set on the initial setup

[image]

Comment: Is it your own Wi-Fi network or public?

Comment: thats my home network
also tried my phone hotspot 
its not promting for the PSK for all networks

its not working on the wingpanel nor in the network settings

Comment: I do not understand that it is not prompting for psk. PSK is encryption method. How you are setting up your router? What is the model of the router?

Comment: ah sorry... PreSharedKey, the password
so I am not able to set the password due its not prompting for it 
I have different access point models (Cisco, Alcatel and linksys) and I also tried it on different locations and SSIDs

Comment: its just one SSID with WPA2 authentication

Comment: How exactly you are setting up the Wi-Fi network on your router? My Elementary OS is connecting without any issue to the network I created on router. I set password on router for the SSID and chosen the WPA-2 encryption.

Comment: its set up the same. all my other devices are working and eOS should come up with an entry field where I can put in my password if no WLAN profile has been created yet which is not the case

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327197 But I do not know will it solve your issue. It may be related to network adapter driver.

Comment: Eventually https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant

Comment: I have added the wpa supplicats manually and I am still not able to join the WIFI.
@Sysadmin: Thanks for you inputs. I will update on this if its solved

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the WIFI password in the network settings on Security to be able to connect to it.